# Display real time data in text label d3.js

Tags: d3.js, label, real-time

I have a line graph that is updating as data is pulled in at 5 second intervals from a database.

https://gist.github.com/Majella/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

I wanted to add a label to the top right hand corner of the graph that will display the date/time (stored as variable dateTimeTaken) and update this label as the new data pulled in?

I've been searching online and can't seem to find an example of this anywhere - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite easy. Based on your gist, something like:

```
d3.json("getdata.php", function(error,data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dateTimeTaken = parseDate(d.dateTimeTaken);
    d.reading = +d.reading;
  });
var maxDate = d3.max( data, function(d) { return d.dateTimeTaken; } 

svg.selectAll( ".timeDisplay" )
  .data( [maxDate] )
  .text( function(d) { return d; } )
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "timeDisplay" )
  .attr("x", width )
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("text-anchor", "end" )
  .text( dateTimeTaken );
```

Put this in your "updateData" function.
Given that you are receiving multiple data items, you may need to do a "d3.max()" call on the data to figure out which date you want to display.

Comment: Thanks - getting error message "dateTimeTaken" not defined.  Changed it to d.dateTimeTaken but then "d" is not defined??

Comment: If you are using d.dateTimeTaken, you'll change it to - .text( function(d) { return d.dateTimeTaken; } ). Just depends how you want to access variables.

Comment: I'd tried that too and getting another error "Object [object Array] has no method 'enter'"